# Connect to Azure container registry from microk8s

Tags: azure-container-registry, microk8s

I am trying to pull images from my azure container registry

```
 sudo microk8s ctr --debug images pull redacted.azurecr.io/acs/service:2.24.2
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
ctr: failed to resolve reference "redacted.azurecr.io/acs/service:2.24.2": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Here's my containerd-template.toml config:

```
version = 2

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
    endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io", ]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:32000"]
    endpoint = ["http://localhost:32000"]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."redacted.azurecr.io"]
    endpoint = ["https://redacted.azurecr.io"]
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."redacted.azurecr.io".auth]
    username = "redacted"
    password = "redacted"
```

By adding the username:password to the terminal command I am able to download the image so I am sure user name and password are correct. It looks like the configration from the config file is not being picked up (I did do microk8s stop and microk8s start afer editing the config file)

```
sudo microk8s ctr --debug images pull redacted.azurecr.io/acs/service:2.24.2 -u redacted:redacted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved it by adding a docker secret and patching the service account to use the pull secret as default

```
microk8s kubectl create secret docker-registry acr-token --docker-server=**redacted** --docker-username="**redacted**" --docker-password="**redacted**" --namespace **redacted**

microk8s kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "acr-token"}]}' --namespace **redacted**
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that microk8s was restarted after changing the containerd-template.toml.

> MicroK8s v1.14 and onwards uses containerd. [As described here](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/registry.md), users should be aware of the secure registry and the credentials needed to access it. As shown above, configuring containerd involves editing /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml and reloading the new configuration via a microk8s stop, microk8s start cycle.

[[Reference](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private)]

You can review the following for similar issues:
https://github.com/containerd/cri/issues/1482
https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/990
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4920

Comment: As noted in my question I did restart microk8s after editing the toml config file